# Pyspark - Converting an array of string type elements into a map of key value pairs

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I am attempting to parse the contents of a log file containing call data.

I have been able to transform the log data from a very crude nature to that shown below -- **an array of string type elements where each element is in key:value form**.  Each row represents a different event type and thus has a different "schema".

...
["activeInd:Y", "callerANI:123456789", "storeCode:12345"]
["appCode:123", "exitCode:N", "segmentId:123"]
["storeCode:12345", "store24HourInd:Y", "storePharmacyInd:Y", "storeOpenHour:0800"]
...

**I need to create one map column containing all the key value pairs from the array of strings above so I can .get any key by the "key name"**

(also so i can track all keys per log event type as "schema" versions if new attributes are ever added in the future to any particular log event type)

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in elem.split() for arr in arrs for elem in arr}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Samwise for leading us down the right path...

```
def item_description(item):
arr =  item
returndict = {}
for x in arr:                                  
    arrElem = x.split(":")
    key = arrElem[0]
    value = arrElem[1] 
    returndict.update({key: value})        
return returndict

item_description_udf = udf(item_description,MapType(StringType(),StringType())) 
eventListParsed3DF = eventListParsed3DF.withColumn("events_map",item_description_udf(eventListParsed3DF.events_array))
```

Comment: So you will implement this with pure Python and not pyspark? Or the above code should be part of an UDF?

Comment: The above code is part of a UDF...I am new to SOF...but bear with me... `item_description_udf = udf(item_description,MapType(StringType(),StringType()))`        
`eventListParsed3DF = eventListParsed3DF.withColumn("events_map",item_description_udf(eventListParsed3DF.events_array))`